# How do I change the sheet to which an HTML form writes using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm following [Steven's](https://steven.codes/blog/google-sheets-db-tutorial/) tutorial on writing HTML form data to a google sheet. Specifically, I'm using this app script

```
//  1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
//  2. Run > setup
//
//  3. Publish > Deploy as web app 
//    - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version' 
//    - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously) 
//
//  4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action 
//
//  5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service
// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
return handleResponse(e);
}
function doPost(e){
return handleResponse(e);
}
function handleResponse(e) {
// shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
// this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
// [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
// we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.
/* // If you are passing JSON in the body of the request uncomment this block
var jsonString = e.postData.getDataAsString();
e.parameter = JSON.parse(jsonString);
*/
try {
// next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
// we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
var row = []; 
// loop through the header columns
for (i in headers){
if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
row.push(new Date());
} else { // else use header name to get data
row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
}
}
// more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
// return json success results
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} catch(e){
// if error return this
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} finally { //release lock
lock.releaseLock();
}
}
function setup() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

and the following HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GS DB Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="example-form">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>

    <!-- JQuery POST request. -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#example-form").submit(function(event) {
            var $form = $(this);
            request = $.ajax({
                url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxDGzL3aHSguXkoNtuck3FdoQMpUlJx9S1bs9Zj4ujpiRcXw9Qn/exec",
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $form.serialize(),
            });
            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
            request.fail(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script works perfectly when I run it but something weird happens when I want to change the `SHEET_NAME` from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2" that exists in my google spreadsheet. No data will be written to Sheet2 but the data will be written to Sheet1. When I change the name of Sheet1 to something else, the script does not write any data and throws an error.

This might have something to do with permissions. When I create a new deployment while setting `SHEET_NAME` to, say, Sheet2, data will actually be written to that sheet.

I'm looking for a solution to be able to change the sheet to which the script writes on the fly by just changing the `SHEET_NAME` variable and clicking "save".

Comment: In your situation, after you changed the value of `var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";`, when the version of your Web Apps is updated to the latest one, what result will you obtain? Because from `when I run it but something weird happens when I want to change the SHEET_NAME from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2" that exists in my google spreadsheet. No data will be written to Sheet2 but the data will be written to Sheet1.`, I'm worried that your Web Apps might be not updated by modified script after you modified the script of Web Apps. How about this? If this was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "when the version of your Web Apps is updated to the latest one"? When I change ```var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"``` to ```var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet2"```, the form entries are still sent to Sheet1. When I change the actual name of the sheet from Sheet1 to something else, I receive an unspecified error and no data is written.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. At Web Apps, when the script is modified from `var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"` to `var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet2"`, it is required to update the deployed version by the modified script. When this is not done, the old script is used. I thought that this might be the same as your issue. So I proposed to update the version of Web Apps with the latest script. About the method for updating it, you can see [this document](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43).

Comment: If you are using an `exec` URL, you have to deploy a new version if you want script changes to get reflected in the web app, as Tanaike explained. If you are using the `dev` URL (accessible via `Test deployments`), you won't have to do that, and saving the script after the change will be enough. I mention this because this behavior `When I change the name of Sheet1 to something else, the script does not write any data and throws an error` would only make sense if you were using the `dev` or updating the deployment. So could you please clarify what URL you are using?

Comment: I'm using exec deployment and deploying a new version does the trick. Thanks! Please add this as an answer so I can accept it. A source that explains this would also be nice.

Comment: I'd keep the sheetname in PropertiesService so you can change the sheet name without  having to redeploy the webapp.

Comment: How would I do that @Cooper?

Comment: It's all described in the Apps Script Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

#### Production (/exec):

If you are using a production URL (`/exec`), you have to update the deployment if you want script changes to get reflected in the web app, as [Tanaike explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69308348/how-do-i-change-the-sheet-to-which-an-html-form-writes-using-app-script#comment122501164_69308348).

It should be noted that there's no need to actually [make a new deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app), you can just [edit an existing deployment with a new version](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#new-editor_3):

For that, after changing the script, click `Manage deployments`, and while on the current deployment, click the pencil icon and, on `Version`, select `New version` to edit the deployment with current code.

#### Testing (/dev):

If you were using the `/dev` URL (accessible via `Test deployments`), you won't have to do that, and saving the script after the change will be enough (see [Test a web app deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#test_a_web_app_deployment)):

> This URL ends in `/dev` and can only be accessed by users who have edit access to the script. This instance of the app always runs the most recently saved code and is only intended for testing during development.